# Are one-line answers to terminology questions acceptable?

Tags: discussion, answers, quality

I've noticed the "Low Quality Posts" review topic frequently flags up answers to terminology questions (usually "What should I call X?" questions), which consist of a short, simple answer (usually something along the lines of "You should call it Y").

I find myself agreeing that the posts are low quality, since they never go into detail explaining the answer, and are often just a suggestion rather than a definitive answer. However I don't really know whether they're worth commenting on, downvoting or simply suggesting deletion (though none of the deletion reasons really cover this). Of course I could just be entirely wrong and these could be acceptable answers.

Are they acceptable? If not, what should we do about them?

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion the "You could call it X" answers (with no other information) don't provide value. At the least an answer to a terminology question should explain why the term makes sense to the target audience, and more ideally it should explain why that term is used.

All posts should have some explanation, hence the post notice we have for "Insufficient Explanation", which can be applied to posts as a note to expand an answer (or it may be deleted):

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer: please explain why you're recommending it as a solution. Answers that don't explain anything will be deleted. See Good Subjective, Bad Subjective for more information.

An issue with terminology questions is that often there isn't a real taxonomy to every little thing that's common in design workflows, user workflows or interfaces, and if there isn't a definitive answer there's not much value I feel non-canonical answers bring there.

Answer (score 3):

Only if they have exactly 7 words.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

Is it too much trouble to ask that people at least link to a reference page that names it / defines various terms?